# Do we need multiple indexes on a given column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, indexing

MySQL (Maria)

I've created an index on two columns.

```
entpcd -- Entity Type Code
enid -- Entity ID
```

Will MySQL use this index automatically for this query?

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE entpcd='PN'
```

.. or do I need to define a separte single-field index for `entpcd` so that `SELECT` performs well?

Comment: It will use index entpcd(first column), but still it has to perform key lookup to get rest of columns (SELECT *)

Comment: Ref: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-index/mysql-composite-index/ "_The query optimizer uses the composite indexes for queries that test all columns in the index, or queries that test the first columns, the first two columns, and so on._". As `entpcd` is the first column in the index then no further index is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If MySQL decides to use an index for that query, then the index you created would qualify as one it could use.

I'm being horribly vague because the optimizer will do what the optimizer does. But, if you have enough rows in the table, and that's the only index available, it will be able to use that index.

Comment: Phrased differently:  The Optimizer only needs `entpcd` for _that_ query; it will pick from among all `INDEXes` that _start_ with `entpcd`.